# How to upload a file to SharePoint folder

Tags: android, sharepoint

I've been trying to upload files to my SharePoint 2013 server. I'm doing this from an Android app using REST API.

I can only upload text files (i.e txt/rtf).

This is how I do:

The URL I hit:

```
https://mysite.com/me/username/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/me/username/Documents')/Files/Add(url='testingUpload.txt', overwrite=true)
```

Headers:

```
'Accept' : 'application/json;odata=verbose',
'binaryStringRequestBody' : true,
'state : 'Update',
'X-RequestDigest' : <x-requestDigest>
'Content-Length' : contentLength
```

In the body, I send the contents of the file (in string format).
The problem comes when I upload a PDF, an image or any other non-text file.

Please tell what the correct method would be. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution?

Comment: @PaulVu sorry I don't remember anything. Surprising and sadly I forgot to post what I did. I think you'd need to upload byte or binary representation of the file.

Comment: If you find a solution, post it as answer and I'll mark it accepted.